# How to import xls contact and send email to the list

Tags: python, email, xlrd

I'm trying to use XLRD to read excel file with firstName, lastName, and email address in it.

Question: what type of object do I get after using XLRD, and how could I use the info to send email to all the emails addresses?

Comment: This is fairly straight-forward - what have you attempted so far?

Comment: For the Excel portion of things, check out the [tutorial](http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf).

Comment: @JohnY Hey John - didn't realise you were on SO - have you checked out http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20309/everything-python yet?

Answer (score 0):

i tried these:

....

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('emails.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
email_column = sh.col_values(1)
#for e in email_column:
send_file_zipped('result.zip',email_column )
```

but the result is no good since it cc all emails address.... i would like to send the email one by one....